# Problem executing colcon build with Ros2 Foxy windows

Tags: windows, build, ros2, colcon

I am getting the following tracebacks when I try to colcon build my workspace (I am using Ros2 Foxy in windows):

```
    --- stderr: dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\yimmi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\yimmi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 no es una aplicaci¾n Win32 vßlida
CMake Error at C:/opt/ros/foxy/x64/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/rosidl_generator_py_generate_interfaces.cmake:213 (message):
  execute_process(C:/opt/ros/foxy/x64/python.exe -c 'import
  numpy;print(numpy.get_include())') returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/opt/ros/foxy/x64/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_execute_extensions.cmake:48 (include)
  C:/opt/ros/foxy/x64/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:286 (ament_execute_extensions)
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice this:

```
WinError 193
```

It looks your python runtime version is not match Numpy (CPU arch different?). Maybe you had installed Anacoda and it overrides the default python path.

You could try to check your python path.